# Viewing all tabs in one window in Gmail

Tags: gmail

How can I get a Gmail appearance such that all of the mails in my email tabs (Inbox, Sent Mail etc.) are visible in one window? I should be able to see all of my emails in one big window, without having to click on tabs on the left hand-side. I know it is possible because I have seen my friend do it, but I don't know how!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you want to accomplish, you should set your inbox to default and disable the *categories* tabbing.

1. Click on the gear icon in the upper-right corner;
2. Click on *Settings*;
3. Go to the *Inbox* tab (the third one);
4. For *Inbox Type* choose **Default**;
5. Deselect any other option except **Primary** from the *Categories*;
   [image]
6. Click **Save Changes** at the bottom of the page.

That’s for an all-incoming-mail-in-the-same-window inbox. Otherwise, if you want to see *absolutely everything*, including chats, archived emails and what’s under your labels as well, go to **All Mail** from the left-hand side menu (under Inbox, Sent Mail etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort! However, my question is still unanswered and I don't know how to properly word what I'm asking.

Comment: It’s probably the _All Mail_ what you saw, but there is no setting for making it the default view.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably the "All Mail" item.

> [What is 'All Mail'?](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6581)
>
> All Mail is your archive, a storage place for all the mail you've ever sent or received, but have not deleted.
>
> You can see a list of archived messages by clicking All Mail. If the All Mail link is not visible by default in your inbox, click on the More dropdown menu under your Labels list to visualize it. Archived messages are also available by searching, and under any assigned labels.

"All mail" shows *all* of your mail messages, no matter what their label(s) might be<sup>1</sup> *except* for the message in your **Spam** and **Trash** buckets.

[image: screen shot]

<sup>1</sup> "Inbox" is just a label, albeit a special one.